# Accessing Data inside a hash returned from a database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash

I'm a PHP developer getting into Ruby on Rails. I'm working on a project where a collection of strings is serialized and stored in a database. I'm trying to access that data, but inside a mailer class I'm writing but am having troubles. Inside the Model where the data is being taken out of the DB, I can access what I need by using `email.attr(key,'subject')`, however when I pass the email variable to the mailer class and try to use that same method of access inside the mailer class I get an `"undefined variable 'key'"` error message.

Here is a dump of the data when I run email.inspect.

```
{"subject"=>"Subject of Email", "intro"=>"Welcome"}
```

My search results in Google did not return anything helpful.

Comment: hey, you should post more of your code.

Answer (score 2):

Typically, you would access data in a hash by doing something like:

```
email["subject"]
```

In your case, it looks like the email object has attributes, so it's not a hash but an actual object. In this case, assuming you have an attr_reader for both subject and intro, you would do:

```
email.subject
```

However, I think the bug in your above example might be b/c the word 'key' in the method call isn't quoted (hence, it's treating it like a variable). Just a guess though as I've never seen an attribute accessed through an attr method.

Comment: Thank you! I have spent several days trying to figure out how to save the data from the response of a json api call. This is exactly what I needed. (I'm a frontend designer moving to rails backend work.)